# Would the USB-C MacBook Pro chargers work with the new (Oct-2018) iPadPro?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, usb, charging

I have been going through the newly launched iPad Pro models and noted that Apple has decided to put a USB-C port rather than Lightning, for charging. Would that mean that one could use the same (87W) charger for the MBP and iPP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPad uses a **13W Power Adapter** while the Macbook Pro, depending on the size uses a **61/81W Power Adapter**.

**Using the Macbook charger with the iPad**

This safe to do so and Apple does mention it in one of their articles, saying it might charge faster.

> If you have a higher-wattage USB-C power adapter — such as the one that came with your Mac notebook — you can use it with iPad Pro, and you might see faster charging. You can also charge iPad Pro by connecting it to the USB-C port on your computer.

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209186#charge))

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious reason why it *shouldn’t* work, but no one can answer for sure until they’ve actually got their hands on one of the new iPad Pro models in a bit over a week.

Comment: I have read some comments about people complaining why Apple chose to go with the 18W charger instead of 30W fast charging adapters, so I figured if it's just a matter of wattage, one could easily use the same adapter as the MBP.